# Flash (Adobe Air) Charting Libraries

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air, charts

We are considering developing an application in Adobe AIR. However, one of the criteria is that we are able to support charting in the user interface.

Some of the charts are real time (updated periodically in a manner that isn't "jerky" to the user.

The application is also stand alone and will not have the use of an http server.

Can anyone suggest a charting library for Adobe Air, open source, or not.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Flex.  Check out the charting components in [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour).